# How I can load Wordpress page in Codeigniter without using iframe

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter, load

Hi I am trying to load a single page of my WordPress site into a Codeigniter project. But without using iframe. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax call into particular div element ? Or html `object` tag.. ?

```
<object style="(width and height in pixels)" type="text/html" data="http://my-wpsite.com" typemustmatch="typemustmatch"> 
  <param name="data" value="http://my-wpsite.com"> 
  Object unavailable at this moment.
</object>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I got my solution.